# The “of” in the “a high level of civilization”

Tags: prepositions

Here is a sentence from *"New Concept English"* Lesson 3:

> "The city must have been prosperous, for it enjoyed a high level **of** civilization."

I am wondering what's the function of *"of"* here? Is it correct to say:

> "a high-level civilization"

or even

> "a high level civilization"?

It should be the *"civilization"* what the city enjoyed, but the *"of"* here makes me feel that the city enjoyed the "*level"*.

Comment: Please look up *civilization* and check out the various meanings. Hint: there are more than one.

Comment: a high level that belongs to civilization.

Answer (score -2):

Its difficult to explain the difference. See if you can understand the difference between the two sentences below.

Original:

> The city must have been prosperous, for it enjoyed a high level of civilization (being civilized - a process).

Proposed:

> The city must have been prosperous, for it **had / contained / was part of** a high-level civilization (an object / entity)

Comment: "a high level of civilization"—I would say "civilization" here is a *property* of the city: very civilized = high amount of civilization. This is similar to saying the air contains high levels of pollen. "A high-level civilization" is a civilization (society) described as high-level, although that descriptor is a bit odd; "an *advanced* civilization" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: You might want to correct its to it's and a capital letter.